# Wix Publish dialog bold font

Tags: fonts, dialog, wix

could you please help me with wix dialogs? I want to hide UI when upgrading already installed application so I find out that I have to use NOT Installed condition in custom UI. THe problem I have is that when I Used publish like so:

```
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">NOT Installed</Publish>
```

the font in all build dialogs (WelcomeDlg, WelcomeEulaDlg etc.) is bold

[image]

but when I use WixUI_InstallDir everything looks ok.

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="InstallDir" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
```

[image]

Do you have any idea what is going on? I just want to use build in dialogs so I don't have to design them all from scratch. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because WixUI_InstallDir.wxs hase defined default font size. This should work for you

```
<Fragment>
  <UI Id="MyWixUI_InstallDir">
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Normal" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="8" />
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Bigger" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="12" />
    <TextStyle Id="WixUI_Font_Title" FaceName="Tahoma" Size="9" Bold="yes" />

    <Property Id="DefaultUIFont" Value="WixUI_Font_Normal" />

    <Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">NOT Installed</Publish>
  </UI>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Common" />
</Fragment>
```